# Where to find the documentation for International Business Machine's Java Server Faces tag library?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, taglib

At my job I have been tasked to work on the frontend in a Java application, which I never did before, since I have been working only on the backend.

The application frontend's view layer is written in JSF packed inside .JSP files.
That is not great for me, as backend boy, but I will probably figure it out with time except there is one problem:

This application uses one taglib, namely http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended for which I was  not able to find the documentation online. The link, of course, does not work in a web browser, and I did a google search for a documentation of this IBM JSF taglib, but I could not find a complete documentation. Without the documentation, it would be pretty hard to understand this application, especially for someone facing JSFs for the first time. If I try Control+space in the  Eclipse on any of the tags from this library, it gives me only tag name without any description of a tag.

For all other taglibs used in that application, like http://java.sun.com/jsf/core for example, I found the documentation without problems.

So does anyone know where to find the documentation of this IBM's library (or at least a guide on how to use it)?

Comment: What is the name of the jar providing the taglib?

Comment: Hmmm, it should be `jsf-ibm-3_1_13`. It is the only one in the project with keywords jsf and ibm in its name, so, this must be it.

Comment: Yes, that is the one, I have checked. It contains the `com.ibm.faces.taglib.html_extended` package inside with all the tags used in jsf page defined.

Comment: Perhaps it is https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-jsf/info ?

Comment: It could be, I am not 100% sure. It does use `hx` as its default prefix. Unfortunately, "documentation" link inside the link which you specified does not work. :(

Comment: That strongly indicates that nobody (asking questions on SO) uses it anymore. You might run into trouble modernizing your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some documentation in the IBM Redbook: *WebSphere Studio 5.1.2 JavaServer Faces and Service Data Objects*. The chapter about the IBM Extension Library starts page 146.

I wasn't able to find this document on IBM's website, but you can download it from the wayback machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20060218093722/https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246361.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20060218101411/http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246361.pdf

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. That book is what I was looking for. I would probably spent days or weeks searching for it without your help.

Comment: You may want to update https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-jsf/info with this information?